# How to use caching to speed up load times? (using GET method)

Tags: php, html, caching

I have a web page that downloads a large amount of preliminary files before showing useful content to users. Sometimes, this can take between 5 and 10 seconds on a standard connection and this can be very frustrating for users to wait for. It's this one file that's taking 90% of the time to load, so I want to do something about it.

I've done some reading about caching... is it possible to have this file's data cached so that it can be loaded instantly next time?

The URL it's obtaining information from looks like this: getData.php?id=A5324DFJK4

This data is being obtained through an AJAX call that returns XML data (then parsed by the app). The reason I used GET is to have it so that particular ID can be cached (I hope I'm right in doing this, the content varies dependent on the ID so I thought caching each one would make sense).

The actual platform the code to cache it would be executed on is a mobile phone, I'm using PhoneGap to build the app when finished. If anyone could enlighten me as to how I could use caching to improve my situation I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the browser will cache pages for each individual ID. It's up to you to tell the browser how long you wish to cache this data for. As you've said it's XML, it can be included in the headers for XML you print right now in your getData.php script.

E.g.:

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('+2 days')) . ' GMT');
header("Content-type: text/xml");
header("Pragma: cache");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This certainly seems like a good way to do things... is there any simple way of having it cache the content on first download and then each time check if it has changed (if it has changed, download and cache new data, if it hasn't just use the cached file)?

Comment: You can't have that cake and eat it too, but ask yourself why you want it in the first place. getData.php?id=A5324DFJK4 implies it's a very specific resource, with ID A5324DFJK4, why would it be relevant at what time it would've been retrieved?

If it is that relevant - why cache it in the first place?

Comment: The only other way I could think of is comparing the current time to the filemtime() of your getData.php file, and if it falls within the X of time you set for cache, then send header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");//Past.

However this will make _all_ requests uncachable within that timeframe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right, it is a specific resource. Let's say that there will be lots of people using this application, and depending where you are the ID will vary, but most of the time people will use the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

Can you process the data further on the server and cache it there? There really isn't much to go with your problem description.

Example on caching something created with PHP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#61903